# Get distinct Combinations of numbers using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, combinations

The below code returns all distinct combinations based on the logic that 1,2,3 = 3,2,1 = 2,3,1, so it only returns 1 instance of that set of numbers.

However, I want to change that logic so that it returns ALL instances of all number sets.

What do I need to do to the LINQ query below "GetPowerSet" in order to make that happen?

```
    public void GetPowersets()
    {
        List<int> ints = new List<int>()
        {
            1,2,2,3,3
        };

        var results = GetPowerSet(ints);


        List<String> combinations = new List<String>();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var intValue in result.OrderBy(x => x))
            {
                sb.Append(intValue + ",");
            }
            combinations.Add(sb.ToString());
        }

        string c1 = string.Join("|", combinations.ToArray()).Replace(",|", "|");
        //c1 = "|1|2|1,2|2|1,2|2,2|1,2,2|3|1,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,2,3|1,2,2,3|3|1,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,2,3|1,2,2,3|3,3|1,3,3|2,3,3|1,2,3,3|2,3,3|1,2,3,3|2,2,3,3|1,2,2,3,3,"

    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetPowerSet(List<int> list)
    {
        return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
                     select
                         from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                         where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                         select list[i];
    }
```

This is the end result I am trying to achieve: (no duplicate rows of combinations: duplicate = 3,2,1 and 3,2,1 are the same thing. but 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 are NOT the same thing and both should be in the end result)

```
1
2
3
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,3
2,2
3,1
3,2
3,3
1,2,3
1,2,2
1,3,2
1,3,3
2,1,3
2,1,2
2,3,1
2,3,2
2,3,3
2,2,1
2,2,3
3,1,2
3,1,3
3,2,1
3,2,2
3,2,3
3,3,1
3,3,2
1,2,3,2
1,2,3,3
1,2,2,3
1,3,2,2
1,3,2,3
1,3,3,2
2,1,3,2
2,1,3,3
2,1,2,3
2,3,1,2
2,3,1,3
2,3,2,1
2,3,2,3
2,3,3,1
2,3,3,2
2,2,1,3
2,2,3,1
2,2,3,3
3,1,2,2
3,1,2,3
3,1,3,2
3,2,1,2
3,2,1,3
3,2,2,1
3,2,2,3
3,2,3,1
3,2,3,2
3,3,1,2
3,3,2,1
3,3,2,2
1,2,3,2,3
1,2,3,3,2
1,2,2,3,3
1,3,2,2,3
1,3,2,3,2
1,3,3,2,2
2,1,3,2,3
2,1,3,3,2
2,1,2,3,3
2,3,1,2,3
2,3,1,3,2
2,3,2,1,3
2,3,2,3,1
2,3,3,1,2
2,3,3,2,1
2,2,1,3,3
2,2,3,1,3
2,2,3,3,1
3,1,2,2,3
3,1,2,3,2
3,1,3,2,2
3,2,1,2,3
3,2,1,3,2
3,2,2,1,3
3,2,2,3,1
3,2,3,1,2
3,2,3,2,1
3,3,1,2,2
3,3,2,1,2
3,3,2,2,1
```

The "foreach" way of doing this, which tends to cause a "Out Of Memory Exception" once the number set gets too large (I anticipate LINQ shouldn't have this problem) is below. This works as I want it to, returning the result set I want. But it is slow and has performance issues. I'm also open to suggestions on how to make it better.

```
public List<List<int>> GetAllCombinationsOfAllSizes(List<int> ints)
{
    List<List<int>> returnResult = new List<List<int>>();

    var distinctInts = ints.Distinct().ToList();
    for (int j = 0; j < distinctInts.Count(); j++)
    {
        var number = distinctInts[j];

        var newList = new List<int>();
        newList.Add(number);
        returnResult.Add(newList);

        var listMinusOneObject = ints.Select(x => x).ToList();
        listMinusOneObject.Remove(listMinusOneObject.Where(x => x == number).First());

        if (listMinusOneObject.Count() > 0)
        {
            _GetAllCombinationsOfAllSizes(listMinusOneObject, newList, ref returnResult);
        }
    }

    return returnResult;
}
public void _GetAllCombinationsOfAllSizes(List<int> ints, List<int> growingList, ref List<List<int>> returnResult)
{
    var distinctInts = ints.Distinct().ToList();
    for (int j = 0; j < distinctInts.Count(); j++)
    {
        var number = distinctInts[j];

        var newList = growingList.ToList();
        newList.Add(number);
        returnResult.Add(newList);

        var listMinusOneObject = ints.Select(x => x).ToList();
        listMinusOneObject.Remove(listMinusOneObject.Where(x => x == number).First());

        if (listMinusOneObject.Count() > 0)
        {
            _GetAllCombinationsOfAllSizes(listMinusOneObject, newList, ref returnResult);
        }
    }

}
```

The ANSWER I am looking for is: how to achieve this result set I want , but using LINQ and C# to do it, in a way that is faster and more efficient than the current "foreach" way I have posted?

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote 7 blogs on how to approach this problem - http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: Eric Lippert's blog only appears to discuss how to go about returning all results where the total numbers in that result = 5 (for my example). It doesn't seem to resolve how to return all combinations where total numbers in the sequence < 5. Doesn't resolve my issue. It also doesnt resolve how to avoid duplicate returned results: 1,2,2,3,3 = 1,2,2,3,3 so only 1 instance of it should be in the final result list

Comment: Have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f21b92d-1998-4cc3-b020-56090db5bb68/generating-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-of-numbers?forum=csharplanguage), i think that's what you're looking for. It has a disadvantage though, it considers through ALL the elements of the array, so single values won't be taken in consideration (Calling it multiple times might be needed and some extra work).

Comment: For the duplicate checking, you can do convert to a string and then check. That will definitely get rid of your duplicates. Not sure about performance, though.

Comment: @AsadAli - I already have code that works, but it is slow, that makes use of foreach operators and such. The reason I am trying to figure out how to do this with LINQ is to try to achieve better performance.

Comment: @Ethan - I'm familiar with a possible string.join that can resolve this via a GroupBy statement. However, the larger the result set, the exponentially slower the final result query becomes, as it has exponentially more results it has to filter out, effectively taking longer to compute. Although it is a partial solution to part of the problem, it isn't that efficient. I'm hoping to find a better way through another suggestion! :)

Comment: The current code you have seems to returns all combinations including duplicates.  Not sure what your question is.  Do you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: @n4gy3 The current GetPowerSet code returns this:  |1|2|1,2|2|1,2|2,2|1,2,2|3|1,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,2,3|1,2,2,3|3|1,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,3|1,2,3|2,2,3|1,2,2,3|3,3|1,3,3|2,3,3|1,2,3,3|2,3,3|1,2,3,3|2,2,3,3|1,2,2,3,3, --- which you'll notice almost all of those start with a "1". Compare this set to my question's "end result I am trying to achieve". Based on this, you could say that the current GetPowerSet is removing 'duplicates' (it thinks 1,2,3 = 3,2,1), and I do not want it to remove those duplicates. However, I do not want "duplicate rows" such as multiple returns of "3,2,1" and "3,2,1"

Comment: Might be better suited for the code review SE

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Thanks! didn't know that place existed. Posted: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51938/out-of-memory-error-get-distinct-combinations-of-numbers-using-linq-c

Comment: You *can* do it in LINQ and it will likely be much more readable and understandable of what's going on, but Ulugbek's Dictionary way should be considerably faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW UPDATE** (removed old code, performance is better than OP's code, yielded output)

```
static IEnumerable<int[]> EnumeratePermutations2(int[] ints)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> intCounts = ints.GroupBy(n => n)
                                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    int[] distincts = intCounts.Keys.ToArray();
    foreach (int[] permutation in EnumeratePermutations2(new int[0], intCounts, distincts))
        yield return permutation;
}

static IEnumerable<int[]> EnumeratePermutations2(int[] prefix, Dictionary<int, int> intCounts, int[] distincts)
{
    foreach (int n in distincts)
    {
        int[] newPrefix = new int[prefix.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(prefix, newPrefix, prefix.Length);
        newPrefix[prefix.Length] = n;
        yield return newPrefix;
        intCounts[n]--;
        int[] newDistincts = intCounts[n] > 0
                             ? distincts
                             : distincts.Where(x => x != n).ToArray();
        foreach (int[] permutation in EnumeratePermutations2(newPrefix, intCounts, newDistincts))
            yield return permutation;
        intCounts[n]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about all sequences beginning with a 1?

Comment: @arserbin3 oops, my fault, going to fix it

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It appears that although your solution provides the desired result as does my "GetAllCombinationsOfAllSizes" - your solution happens to be much slower.  Example:  `GetAllCombinationsOfAllSizes({ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6 })`
            vs 
`EnumeratePermutations({ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6 }).Select(x=>x.ToList()).ToList()` results in my way takes 0.04 seconds and your way takes 6.95 seconds

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov just for fun I implemented your way to see what happened in the code - and implemented it without any .ToList() (which slows it down) -- it ended up causing not only an OutOfMemory exception but crashed Visual Studio entirely hahahahah so unfortunately I'm afraid your solution won't help resolve my problem of needing a more efficient solution ;)

Comment: @SED What set did you use to cause OutOfMemory exception? It cannot cause OutOfMemoryException until you try to save everything into the list.

Comment: tried: 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6 and also where it crashed was likely the ToList portion of: `EnumeratePermutations({ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6 }).Select(x=>x.ToList()).ToList()`

Comment: @SED I updated the code, now it has performance better than the code you provided and it is more clear. The `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6` takes 0.058s with my code, and 0.09s with your code.

Comment: @SED On `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8` set my code takes 17s for `.Count()` and 31s for `.ToList()`, while yours executes in 109s.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question.

Your solution does return all result sets including duplicates.  Your solutions does not exclude duplicates.  Your Example output does exclude some duplicates but you list 89 sets of data.

There should only be 64 with duplicates as I understand how combinations work which is 2 ^ List.Count() = 2 ^ 6 = 64 combinations

**Revised Answer**

I believe this is close to what you want.  I created a short solution but I think it can be re factored and enhanced for speed.  The following Link has some good Set Classes which I think should be used:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23391/Set-Collections-for-C

The other thing I would use is the **TPL Library** which will allow you to speed up the processing.  Link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My Result Set resulted in 190 sets.  With the following code it took about 1.5 minutes to run.

**Main Program**

```
void Main()
{
    var setList = new List<int>() {1,1,2,3,3,3};
    var setSize = setList.Count();

    var basePowerSet = PowerSet.Generate(setList);
    var results = PowerSet.PS;


    // Results generated in 1 Minute 23 seconds with no errors.

    var sortedSets = new SortedSet<string>();

    foreach( var item in results)
    {
        sortedSets.Add(item.ToString2());
    }

    foreach( var item in sortedSets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }   


}
```

**PowerSet Library**

```
public static class PowerSet
{
    // List with no Exact Duplicates but with Permutations
    public static List<List<int>> PS =  new List<List<int>>();


    // This Method Generates the power set with No Exact Duplicates
    // and stores the values into the Property PS.
    public static List<List<int>> Generate(List<int> setList)
    {
        // Generate Base Data to use for final results
        var setSize = setList.Count();
        var basePowerSet = from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << setSize)
                select
                    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, setSize)
                    where (m & (1 << i)) != 0 
                    select setList[i];

        // Temporary Result Set with Duplicates
        var results = new List<List<int>>();

        // Step thru each set and generate list of Permutations for each
        // Power Set generated above.
        foreach( var item in basePowerSet )
        {
            var size = item.Count();
            var positions = from m in Enumerable.Range(0, size)
                select m;

            var lItem = item.ToList();  

            // If the set has 2 or more elements in the set then generate Permutations
            switch(size)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    break;
                default:

                    // Permutations generated from Linq Extension defined
                    // in Method Permute()
                    var posList = positions.Permute().ToList();

                    // remove first item which is a duplicate.
                    posList.RemoveAt(0);

                    // Generate new Lists based on all possiable
                    // combinations of the data in the set.
                    var x = new List<List<int>>();
                    foreach(var p in posList)
                    {   
                        var y = new List<int>();
                        foreach(var v in p)
                        {
                            //v.Dump("xxxx");
                            y.Add(lItem[v]);
                        }

                        x.Add(y);

                        // Add New Permutation but
                        // Do not add a duplicate set.
                        AddNonDuplicate(x);
                    }                                       
                    break;
            }

            // Add to Temp Results;
            results.Add(item.ToList());

            // Remove Duplicates
            AddNonDuplicate(results);
        }

        return results;
    }


    // Custom Method used to compare values in a set to the
    // Final Result Set named PS.
    public static void AddNonDuplicate(List<List<int>> list )
    {
        //list.Dump();
        if(list.Count() == 0)
            return;

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            bool found = false;
            var mySize = PS.Count();
            if(mySize <= 0)
                PS.Add(item);
            else
                foreach(var psItem in PS)
                {
                    if( item.ToString2() == psItem.ToString2() )
                        found = true;
                }

            if(!found)
                PS.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**Extension Library**

```
// My Extension Methods
public static class MyExt
{

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (list.Count() == 1)
            return new List<IEnumerable<T>> { list };
        return list
            .Select((a, i1) => 
                        Permute(list.Where((b, i2) => i2 != i1))
                    .Select(b => (new List<T> { a }).Union(b)))
            .SelectMany(c => c);
    }


    public static string ToString2<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder("{ ");
        var size = list.Count();
        var pos = 1;

        foreach( var i in list )
        {
            results.Append(i.ToString());
            if(pos++!=size)
                results.Append(", ");
        }

        results.Append(" }");               
        return results.ToString().Trim(',');
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
{  }
{ 1 }
{ 1, 1 }
{ 1, 1, 2 }
{ 1, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 2 }
{ 1, 2, 1 }
{ 1, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 2 }
{ 2, 1 }
{ 2, 1, 1 }
{ 2, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3 }
{ 3, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 2 }
{ 3, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 1, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 3 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 1, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 2 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 }
{ 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1 }
```

Comment: The current code returns 1,2,3 and does NOT return 3,2,1 -- this is "wrong": I want it to return 3,2,1 as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  So for this example the number of permutations would be 6 factorial = 720 sets of data.  Is this correct?

Comment: @SED  I have modified my Answer.  I have generated 189 items which should not contain any Exact Duplicates but include all permutations.  The results can vary depending on the data set.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't touch your `GetPowerSet`, but instead created a `SetComparer` to filter the repetitions.

```
public class SetComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<int> x, IEnumerable<int> y)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<int> set)
    {
        if (set == null) return 0;

        //if you only want one of these 1,2,3 vs 3,2,1
        //plug .OrderBy(x => x) before the Aggregate
        return set.Aggregate(19, (s,i) => s * 31 + i);
    }
}
```

Just chain `.Distinct(new SetComparer())` to the results or at the end of your `GetPowerSet` select statement.